# Writing a loop that checks the value of a variable against a large number of possible valid values (C++)

Tags: c++, binary, iostream

If there's a better way to word the question, let me know. Probably why I couldn't find it while googling. I'm currently working on a program that searches a binary file for the string of bytes 0xB800000000000000 and then goes back 8 bytes at a time looking for ones that do not fit into a list. For example, the bytes 0x04, 0x06, 0xB1, 0xB7 (and tons of others) are valid, but 0x00, 0xC1, 0xA9 and almost equally as many as are valid would fail the check, causing the program to dump all of the data between the last found valid byte and the 0xB800000000000000 to a file once it's found an invalid byte. What would be the simplest, cleanest way to compare the variable to every valid value, and halt when it finds one that isn't?

Here's an example of a block of data that I'm looking at. I'd be starting at the B8 near the end, and jumping back 8 bytes until I reach the 0x00 checking the value of the byte every jump.

**00** 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF **BA** 00 14 02 00 00 00 00
**B6** 00 00 00 00 0F 32 05 **B7** 00 00 00 00 00 02 04
**FC** 42 CA 85 FF 97 FF FF **BB** 00 00 00 80 00 80 00
**04** 00 10 3F 80 04 D4 B0 **B1** 02 04 00 00 02 06 04
**B8** 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

I'm not sure how to write the loop. Would I do it say like, 
if (variable != BA | B6 | B7 | FC | BB | 04 | B1) {
blah blah blah}

or is there a better way to write that expression?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] to understand the downvotes

Comment: Create an array of bytes of size **24** and check if the last **16** match the `0xB800000000000000` pattern, then validate the previous **8** ones? Repeat the process by 'moving' the array 1 byte further (read 1 more byte and assign it to the last byte of the array after you move every previous one backwards, discarding the first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use std::any_of or std::none_of depending on what gives you the lowest search range.

```
std::vector<int> valid_bytes { 3,5,7,8,12,15 };
if (std::any_of(valid_bytes.begin(), valid_bytes.end(), [=](int x){ return x == the_byte_to_check; }) {
    //The byte is valid!
}
```

If it instead is better to check against a vector filled with the invalid bytes, you can use std::none_of to see that it's not matching any of the invalid bytes.

```
std::vector<int> invalid_bytes { 3,5,7,8,12,15 };
if (std::none_of(invalid_bytes.begin(), invalid_bytes.end(), [=](int x){ return x == the_byte_to_check; }) {
    //The byte is valid!
}
```